# Silvering of lenses and their focal length

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

For a silvered biconvex lens the equivalent power is give by $P_{eqv.}=P_{lens}+P_{mirror}+P_{lens}$.  Here we put power of lens as negative since it behaves as a concave mirror overall.

Reasoning for using power of lens twice is given that is passes through lens twice and hence is refracted twice. However, it is getting refracted only on one surface and refraction by second surface is not happening at all. Why is then this formula valid?

Comment: Many related/duplicate questions? [silvered biconvex lens site:physics.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=silvered+biconvex+lens+site:physics.stackexchange.com&client=firefox-b-d&sca_esv=588018538&sxsrf=AM9HkKn08repCEVqrBUDsnhadBCsgaUIuQ:1701781424849&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif3sDqrfiCAxVH2aQKHRgCBLEQrQIoBHoECDcQBQ&biw=1548&bih=929&dpr=1.2#ip=1)